# google maps infowindow directions link

Tags: jquery, google-maps, infowindow

I have included google maps into my homepage for my customers to be able to find me easily. My problem is that i couldn't find a way to include the directions link like here:

[image: Direct link example]

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.562944, 16.079245);
    var myOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),  myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Mehr Informationen!"
    });

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent("<b>Company</b><br>Street<br>Town"); //sets the       content of your global infowindow to string "Tests: "
    infowindow.open(map,marker); //then opens the infowindow at the marker
});
marker.setMap(map);
});
```

I am an unexperienced user, who is trying to learn and understand. I hope you can help me to solve my problem.